# Match line with some length with pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try use regex in Notepadd++. I need replace each line with some length. For example line length is `6`:

My pattern is:

```
^[^$]{6}$
```

It does not work. What I do not right?

Comment: You are not very clear about what you want ? Can you explain better ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use following regex:

```
^.{6}$
```

`$` is not a character that could be captured or skipped. It's like with `\b` (word boundary) - you can't have two of them in a row.

Comment: Inside the square brackets `$` matches a literal `$`.  If the line doesn't contain any dollar signs, `[^$]{6}` should work just as well as `.{6}`.  It does for me, anyway.  (Note that it's only your *analysis* I'm correcting; he definitely should be using `.`, not `[^$]`.)

Comment: @AlanMoore You're absolutely right. I just figured that Balconsky is trying to match six characters except for EOL (not literal $) :).